# Is it possible to route requests from inside cluster to external endpoint via specific node?

Tags: kubernetes, endpoint

I have a kubernetes cluster v 1.19.4 set up with several nodes and services. Some of these services need to access an external resource residing outside the cluster. I have understood that this external resource can be defined by a service without label selector and then manually creating an Endpoints object to set the resource IP.

My question is one of convenience; the external service needs to be configured to allow connections from distinct IPs, and because of that I'd like to route all requests to this service to be handled by a specific node; so I know that the cluster-services will only communicate to this external resource via a single IP, regardless of from which node the request originates.

Is this possible by assigning nodeSelectors to the service definition in kubernetes or endpoints-object, or by some other means?

The requirement could be described with a networking likeness: I'd like to achieve what a router does for it's clients: present a single ip regardless of which client makes an outbound request to the wan.

thanks

Comment: You should constraint your service to receive traffic from pods with specific labels, or from a namespace, but I would say it is not a good idea to set up a node IP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

services are a virtual thing, there is pod backing them per se so no nodes. However you can run the pod using nodeSelectors and providing hostname IP. Then you can have service communicating to that pod (and specific node) using labels

Comment: is this an answer?

Comment: I think so (clarified a bit) - Don't think svc can be routed to specific worker nodes, thus go via routing pods to reqd node and using labels. May be my little understanding and could be wrong

Comment: thanks arjain13! let me see if I understand your answer; in order to facilitate this I'd need a pod on the desired node acting as reverse proxy basically; all services within the cluster would adress this service, and that would then access the external resource?

Comment: To be honest; its not the right pattern as pointing to a node means compromising the resiliency. You may control the comm from other nodes as well. It should be able to communicate to required endpoints through  a specific node via pod.

Comment: Indeed it is breaking resiliency, and even if there's a way I think I'll consider other approaches instead. I was curious to see if there was an approach as i couldn't find one commonly adopted.